# How to set UICollectionViewCell height based on tallest UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to set the height of my `UICollectionViewCell` and the `UICollectionView` based on the tallest `UILabel`  inside each cell.

For that, this is my attempt:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    let datasource = ["USA", "MGA USA USA USA USA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA", "GER",]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self;
        collectionView.delegate = self;
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10000.0;
    }
    
//    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
//        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
//        let height = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
//        collectionViewHeight.constant = height
//        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//    }
    
    var maxHeight = 0
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    func newMax(){
        
        collectionViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(maxHeight+60)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        
        if let index = indexPath {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [index])
//            collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
        }
        print("collectionViewHeight.constant \(collectionViewHeight.constant)")
    }
    
    func checkMax(height: Int, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath ){
        
        var newMax = height > maxHeight ? height: maxHeight
        if(newMax != maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = newMax
            self.newMax()
            self.indexPath = indexPath
            print("max is \(maxHeight)")
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let cells = collectionView.visibleCells as? Array<CollectionViewCell> else {
            return
        }
        
        for cell in cells {
            let height = cell.countryNameLabel.bounds.size.height
            print(cell.countryNameLabel.text)
            print(height)
            checkMax(height: Int(height), forItemAt: IndexPath(index: 0))
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? CollectionViewCell {
            let height = cell.countryNameLabel.bounds.size.height
            print(cell.countryNameLabel.text)
            print(height)
            
            checkMax(height: Int(height), forItemAt: indexPath)
        } else {
            print(cell.bounds.size.height)
        }
    }
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//            let h =  maxHeight == 0 ?  123: maxHeight
        let h = collectionViewHeight.constant - 30
        print("setting cell size to \(h)")
        return CGSize(width: 123, height: h)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        datasource.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellTemp = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        print("cellTemp \(cellTemp)")
        let cell = cellTemp ?? CollectionViewCell()
        cell.setup(with: datasource[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

As you can see in this GIF, I can't comprehend why the `UICollectionViewCell` randomly disapears on `scroll` . I tried so many things I found on StackOverflow but I am out of luck. That's why I asked this question here.

If my entire approach is wrong and there is a better, please suggest. I also tried so many things I found here but this is the only method that almost works

Answer (score 1):

##### Notes

1. I tried this without autolayout so you would need to add necessary constraints if you are using it with autolayout.
2. While this seems to work out for this particular use case, you will definitely need to adapt this idea to your use case.

---

##### What might be the source of the problem?

The code inside `newMax()` calls -

1. `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`
2. `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [index])`

And `newMax()` itself is triggered like -
`willDisplay cell` > `checkMax()` > `newMax()`

This means that you are **potentially** calling `invalidateLayout()` & `reloadItems` way too frequently from within `willDisplay cell`.

---

##### How to solve without calling `invalidateLayout()`?

1. Have a fixed itemSize for the collectionView layout.
2. Allow cell's contentView & label to draw outside of cell (vertically).
3. At least trying it out should not hurt.

---

###### CountryNameCollectionViewCell

```
class CountryNameCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let cellIdentifier = String(describing: self)
    static let preferredWidth: CGFloat = 120
    
    var preferredWidth: CGFloat { CountryNameCollectionViewCell.preferredWidth }
    var labelHeight: CGFloat { titleLabel.bounds.height }
    
    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: preferredWidth, height: 0))
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32)
        label.textColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        return label
    }()
    
    func populate(title: String) {
        titleLabel.text = title
        
        let updatedHeight = titleLabel.sizeThatFits(
            CGSize(width: preferredWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        ).height
        
        // Hacky part
        // Needed height/size is applied to contentView as well as titleLabel
        // We have a guarantee from call site that -
        // collectionView will be as tall as we need based on this height
        let updatedSize = CGSize(width: preferredWidth, height: updatedHeight)
        let updatedFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: updatedSize)
        self.contentView.frame = updatedFrame
        titleLabel.frame = updatedFrame
    }
    
}
```

---

###### TopAlignedFlowLayout

```
/// Needed for making all the cells/items stick to top
class TopAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var topSpace: CGFloat = 20
    var attributesCache: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        self.attributesCache = [:]
        
        guard let cv = self.collectionView else { return }
        
        for s in 0..<cv.numberOfSections {
            for i in 0..<cv.numberOfItems(inSection: s) {
                let ip = IndexPath(item: i, section: s)
                
                let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: ip)
                attributes?.frame.origin.y = topSpace
                attributesCache[ip] = attributes
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        var updatedAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        attributes?.forEach({ attr in
            let ip = attr.indexPath
            if let updatedAttr = attributesCache[ip] {
                updatedAttributes.append(updatedAttr)
            }
        })
        
        return updatedAttributes
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        
        var updatedAttributes = attributes
        if let ip = attributes?.indexPath, let updated = attributesCache[ip] {
            updatedAttributes = updated
        }
        
        return updatedAttributes
    }
}
```

---

###### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    // MARK: - Instance Variables
    let minCollectionViewHeight: CGFloat = 80 // including top/bottom insets
    let cvOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
    
    lazy var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
        
        let layout = TopAlignedFlowLayout()
        layout.topSpace = sectionInset.top
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.sectionInset = sectionInset
        
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(
            width: CountryNameCollectionViewCell.preferredWidth,
            height: minCollectionViewHeight - (sectionInset.top + sectionInset.bottom) - 2
        )
        
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = self.view.bounds.height
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
        
        return layout
    }()
    
    lazy var countriesCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: minCollectionViewHeight)
        let frame = CGRect(origin: cvOrigin, size: size)
        
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        cv.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        cv.backgroundColor = .red
        cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        
        self.view.addSubview(cv)
        return cv
    }()
    
    let countries = [
        "USA",
        "MGA USA",
        "FRA USA USA",
        "GER USA USA USA",
        "MGA USA USA USA USA",
        "FRA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "GER USA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "MGA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "FRA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "GER USA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "MGA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA USA",
        "FRA",
        "GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA",
        "MGA USA USA",
        "FRA",
        "GER USA USA USA",
        "MGA",
        "GER USA USA USA USA  USA",
        "GER",
    ]
    
    
    // MARK: - View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        countriesCollectionView.register(
            CountryNameCollectionViewCell.self,
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CountryNameCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier
        )
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource Methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        countries.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CountryNameCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CountryNameCollectionViewCell
        cell.populate(title: countries[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate Methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.updateCurrentHeight(for: cell, incoming: true)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.updateCurrentHeight(for: cell, incoming: false)
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            guard self.isViewLoaded else { return }
            
            heightUpdateWorkItem?.cancel()
            
            let workItem = DispatchWorkItem { self.updateCollectionViewHeight() }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: workItem)
            heightUpdateWorkItem = workItem
        }
    }
    var heightUpdateWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    
    private func updateCurrentHeight(for cell: UICollectionViewCell, incoming: Bool) {
        var updatedHeight: CGFloat = 0
        let inset = flowLayout.sectionInset
        
        if incoming, let countryNameCell = cell as? CountryNameCollectionViewCell {
            let idealHeight = inset.top + countryNameCell.labelHeight + inset.bottom
            updatedHeight = max(minCollectionViewHeight, idealHeight)
        }
        else if var cells = countriesCollectionView.visibleCells as? [CountryNameCollectionViewCell] {
            cells.removeAll(where: { $0 === cell })
            let maxLabelHeight = cells.map({ $0.labelHeight }).max() ?? 0
            updatedHeight = inset.top + maxLabelHeight + inset.bottom
        }
        
        if updatedHeight > 0, updatedHeight != currentHeight {
            if (incoming && updatedHeight > currentHeight) ||
                (!incoming && updatedHeight < currentHeight) {
                currentHeight = updatedHeight
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateCollectionViewHeight() {
        countriesCollectionView.frame = CGRect(
            origin: cvOrigin,
            size: CGSize(width: countriesCollectionView.bounds.width, height: currentHeight)
        )
        print("currentHeight: \(currentHeight)")
    }
    
}
```

---

###### How it looks?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by calculating the Height of Labels inside collectionView. May be the problem is we need a height of label before populating data in collection view.

1. So Make one more array of type `[CGFloat]`.
2. store heights of all labels by using this `extension`.
3. Fetch the highest value from array and store it in separate variable.
4. Use this variable in `sizeForItemAt indexPath` method.

   ```
   func calculateHeight() -> CGFloat?{
   let datasource = ["USA", "MGA USA USA USA USA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "FRA", "GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA", "MGA", "FRA", "GER", "MGA", "GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA GER USA USA USA USA  USA USA", "GER"]
   var arrayHeight: [CGFloat] = []
   for data in datasource
   {
       let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
       label.text = data
       arrayHeight.append(label.requiredHeight)
   }

   return arrayHeight.max()    }
   ```

   extension UILabel{

   ```
   public var requiredHeight: CGFloat {
       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
       label.numberOfLines = 0
       label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
       label.font = font
       label.text = text
       label.attributedText = attributedText
       label.sizeToFit()
       return label.frame.height
   }}
   ```